# building a string with iterators

Tags: c++, string

given a string `s` of type `std::string` I build **another** string `s2` like so

```
std::string(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.find(" "))
```

but the following constructor doesn't work

```
std::string(s.begin(), s.find(" "))
```

anyone knows why ? I'm using `g++ 4.8.1 under Ubuntu amd64`

Both constructors have an iterator as second argument.

In this example I'm trying to build a string containing the first sub-string that ends where the first whitespace appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::find()` returns an offset, not an iterator (yes, it's largely a design inconsistency of the standard library). So to use this (and include proper error checking), do something like this:

```
size_t offset = s.find(" ");
std::string(s.begin(), (offset == std::string::npos ? s.end() : s.begin() + offset);
```

Comment: oh, thanks, I don't know why I was really convinced to deal with an iterator, I assume that after dealing a lot with streams and `char`s you expect something like that ...

Comment: @user2485710: Perhaps you were thinking of the [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm, which returns an iterator?

Comment: most likely, yes, but still can't understand why there is such approach for the `string::` namespace. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @user2485710: I was never sure why the `std::string` *type* needed a `::find()`, since there is a perfectly good free function, the fact that it has a different return type just adds to the confusion.

Comment: @Johnsyweb It seem Herb Sutter [feels similarly](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm).

Comment: @Angew: Indeed he does, he also highlights caution with trying to implement `std::string::find()` in terms of `std::find()`, but for searching for a single element (`char`), I think we're good with `std::find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `find` returns an index (`size_type`). Because a string is a contiguous container, `s.begin() + s.find(" ")` will return you an iterator, as it is equivalent to calling `std::string::iterator operator+=(std::string::size_type s)`. The second one will of course be a compilation error.

Comment: is this the most efficient way of getting this kind of substring ?

Comment: Any way of getting the substring is going to be roughly the same performance: they're all going to be `O(n)`, that is.

Comment: ok, I was thinking about a method that works by predicate and returns a copy of the substring matching that predicate, but I was expecting something like O(n). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were thinking of the [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm, which returns an iterator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Derek Smalls";
    std::string s2(std::begin(s), std::find(std::begin(s), std::end(s), ' '));
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run](http://ideone.com/65wJJU)!